# Angular: Service Observable doesn't fire in component

Tags: angular, typescript

my effects when erring, calls a method in service to display a dialogue. When dialogue completes, it puts result into an observable.

I have a component that is listening to that observable inside that service. Problem is that the component listens to service the very first time and then it doesn't hear anything.

I'm setting that subject to avoid getting the error message that for first time this.errorService.errorExist$ is not returning anything.

ErrorService

```
private errorExist = new Subject<boolean>();
errorExist$ = this.errorExist.asObservable();

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
this.errorExist.next(false);
}

handleError() {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
  data: {
    title: 'Error Occurred',
    btn: 'OKAY'
  }
});
dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(take(1)).subscribe( (result: boolean) => {
  console.log('inside the closed and result is: ', result);
  if (result) {
    this.errorExist.next(true);
  }
});
}
```

Component

```
constructor(errorService: ErrorService) { }
private subscribeToError() {
  this.errorService.errorExist$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((x: boolean) => {
    console.log('this does not print');
    if (x) {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would  recommend the rxjs library.

Change the errorexist's Subject to a Behaviour subject.

Behaviour subject is such a subject which can be listened at multiple times and also has a starting value.